# A discrete problem about coordinates or angle?

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, angle

Suppose there are two straight lines. We call one of them line $a$ and another one line $b$ and they make a $60$ degree angle. Now we start from one point on $b$ and draw a line from that point to line $a$; we let this line be $d$ units long. Now from that new point on line $a$ we draw it back to line $b$ with the same distance $d$(can't take the same path that is used to come to the point). Now continue this process until we get back to the original point. A diagram of how it is done is shown below:( p0 is the original point)
[image]

Prove or disprove: no matter where we start on line $b$ we will get back to the original point.

So I have tried to use trigonometry to bash out the coordinates but it quickly turns to hard and complicated to advance. I am just really confused where to start this off. Some hints will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't know yet whether $p_5$ is $d$ units from $p_0.$  But, you do know that you have a whole bunch of isosceles triangles.    Assign one of the angles to equal $\theta$ and calculate what the others must be.  From there you can show that some triangles are congruent to each other.

Comment: I also tried to use this angle approach; however I don't think there are much things I could get from here as not a lot of angles are the same.

Comment: You can prove that $\angle OP_0P_1 \cong \angle OP_2P_3$ and by law of sines, $OP_0 = OP_3.$  From there to $\triangle OP_0P_1 \cong  \triangle OP_3P_4$ and $\triangle OP_4P_5 \cong \triangle OP_1P_2$

Comment: See my answer to this more general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613457/a-compass-moving-on-two-straight-lines/2613641

Comment: um should i delete this because its a replicate?

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything I wouldn't call this question a duplicate. It may be a special case that can be solved using the answer to the other question, *but* (a) special cases often allow for different, possibly simpler, solutions, and (b) special cases may have additional properties that the general case doesn't. For example, my answer proves in fact the stronger statement that a sufficient condition for the path to close i.e. $P_6 \equiv P_0$ is $P_0P_1=P_1P_2=P_2P_3$ and $P_3P_4=P_4P_5=P_5P_6$, in other words not *all* $6$ distances need to be equal, it's enough that those two triples are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a coordinate on line $b$ having $O$ as origin, and let $p_0$, $p_2$, $p_4$, ... be the coordinates of the points. Using the technique explained in [this answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613457/a-compass-moving-on-two-straight-lines/2613641#2613641), one finds that

$$
p_{n}=p_0\cos{n\pi\over3}\pm{\sqrt{{4\over3}d^2-p_0^2}}\sin{n\pi\over3},
$$

where the choice of sign depends on the direction taken at the first step of the construction.

It follows in particular that $p_6=p_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, let $OP_1=2$ and let $X$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $P_1$ to $OP_2$. Also let angle $XP_1P_0=\theta$.

It is sufficient to show that if $P_0P_1=P_1P_2=d$, and that $P_3$ is a point on $P_1O$ produced such that $OP_0=OP_3$, then $P_2P_3=d$. It will then follow by symmetry that all six red lines are equal, and that such a construction is always possible provided $\sqrt{3}\leq d\leq2$.

This claim follows because, following the construction described, we have $OP_3=1-d\sin\theta$ and $OP_2=1+d\sin\theta$ and the cosine rule in triangle $OP_2P_3$ gives $$P_2P_3^2=(1-d\sin\theta)^2+(1+d\sin\theta)^2-2(1-d^2\sin^2\theta)\cos120=3+d^2\sin^2\theta$$

However, $$\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{d}\implies\sin^2\theta=1-\frac{3}{d^2}$$

Hence $P_2P_3=d$ QED

Comment: sorry i don't understand the construction part... How is the construction always possible after we know the line segments have equal length?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't take much trigonometry; in a 30-60-90 right triangle, consider
the ratio of the short leg to the hypotenuse.

Suppose you have followed the construction of the points $p_0$ to $p_5$ in sequence but have not yet constructed the next point after $p_5.$ It is necessary to prove that that a segment of the same length as the others closes the loop, that is, $p_5p_0 = p_0p_1,$ and therefore that when you *do* plot the next point after $p_5$ it will coincide with $p_0$ and repeat the sequence.

From $p_3$ drop a perpendicular to $Op_4$; call the foot of this perpendicular $p_6.$
Place point $p_7$ on the line $Op_2$ so that $O$ is the midpoint of $p_4p_7.$

Let $d = p_6O$. That is, $d$ is the length of the shorter leg of the
30-60-90 right triangle $\triangle p_3 p_6 O.$
Let $r = Op_4 = Op_7.$

Find the distances $p_0p_6,$ $p_4p_6,$ $p_6p_2,$ and $p_2p_7$ in terms of $d$ and/or $r.$
Using congruent triangles, find $Op_0$ in terms of $d$ and/or $r.$
Show that $Op_3 = Op_0,$ and proceed to show (using congruent triangles)
that $Op_1 = Op_4$ and that $p_5p_0 = p_2p_3.$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure at all but here is my thoughts on maybe how to solve this; comments or corrections toward this solution would be greatly appreciated:

Let the point that $P_5$ goes be $P_6$. We need to prove $P_6$ coincide with $P_0$.

Note that with all line segments being equal, $P_4P_5$=$P_5P_6$. So $\triangle P_4P_5P_6$ is an isosceles triangle.

Since we know $P_4P_5P_6$ is an isosceles triangle we also know that $\angle OP_4P_5$= $\angle OP_6P_5$.  But that will only happen when $P_6$ coincide with $P_0$ so we are done.

Answer (score 0):

The following will prove that $\,\overrightarrow{OP_3}\,$ is $\,\overrightarrow{OP_0}\,$ rotated $\,120^\circ\,$ clockwise, meaning that $P_3$ is univocally determined by $\,P_0\,$ and does not depend on the choice of $\,P_1\,$. The conclusion of the problem then follows directly, since it means that the paths $\,P_0 \,\text{-}\, P_1 \,\text{-}\, P_2 \,\text{-}\, P_3\,$ and  $\,P_0 \,\text{-}\, P_5 \,\text{-}\, P_4 \,\text{-}\, P_3\,$ have $\,P_3\,$ as a common point, so the sequence $\,P_0 \,\text{-}\, P_1 \,\text{-}\, P_2 \,\text{-}\, P_3 \,\text{-}\, P_4 \,\text{-}\, P_5 \,\text{-}\, P_0\,$ is closed.

To prove the proposition, consider the complex plane with the origin at the intersection of the two lines, and the real axis along the blue line. Let $\,\color{blue}{p_0=a}\,$, $\,\color{blue}{p_1=b\omega}\,$ with $\,a,b \in \mathbb{R}\,$ and $\,\omega = e^{i \pi / 3}\,$ $=\cos \frac{\pi}{3}+ i \sin \frac{\pi}{3}\,$ where $|\omega|=1$ and $\,\omega + \bar \omega = 1\,$. The common distance $\,d\,$ is then given by:

$$
d^2=|p_0-p_1|^2 = (a- b \omega)(a - b \bar \omega)=a^2+b^2|\omega|^2-ab(\omega + \bar \omega) = a^2-ab+b^2
$$

- Point $\,p_2\,$ lies on the real axis, so it is $\,p_2 = c \in \mathbb{R}\,$. The condition that $\,|p_2-p_1|=s\,$ gives:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  a^2-ab+b^2 = |c-b\omega|^2 = c^2 + b^2 -bc \;\;&\iff\;\; c^2 - bc + ab-a^2 = 0 \\
   &\iff\;\; (c-a)(c+a-b) = 0
  \end{align}
  $$
  Since $p_2 \ne p_0$ it follows that $\,c-a\ne 0$, which leaves $\,c+a-b=0\,$, so $\,\color{blue}{p_2 = b-a}\,$.
- Point $\,p_3\,$ lies on the line $\,op_1\,$ so it is of the form $\,p_3 = \lambda \omega \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\,$. The distance condition is:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  &a^2-ab+b^2 = |\lambda\omega-(b-a)|^2 = \lambda^2 + (b-a)^2-\lambda(b-a) \\
  &\quad\iff\quad \lambda^2 - \lambda(b-a) -ab = 0 \\
  &\quad\iff\quad (\lambda - b)(\lambda+a) = 0 \\
  \end{align}
  $$
  Since $p_3 \ne p_1$ it follows that $\,\lambda-b\ne 0$, which leaves $\,\lambda+a=0\,$, so $\,\color{blue}{p_3 = -a\omega}\;$ q.e.d.