# A compass moving on two straight lines

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry

Let $a$ and $b$ be two straight lines intersecting at $O$ with an angle $\theta$ between them. Two sequence of points $\{A_n\} \in a$ and $\{B_n\} \in b$ are such that $A_nB_n=A_{n+1}B_n=A_{n+1}B_{n+1}=d$ for a constant $d$ and all $n \geq 1$ and that $A_n \neq A_{n+1}$, $B_n \neq B_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Question

1. Under what conditions (on $\theta$, $A_1$, and $d$) is $\{A_n\}$ a finite set? How to work out $card(\{A_n\})$ and $card(\{B_n\})$, the number of points in those two sets?
2. Under what conditions is $\{A_n\}$ an infinite set?
3. How is the arrangement of $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ changed when the position of $A_1$ changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a direction on $a$ and $b$ and set $a_n=\pm OA_n$, $b_n=\pm OB_n$, where the sign is positive if $A_n$ and $B_n$ are on the positive side of $O$. 
As $B_n$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $A_nA_{n+1}$, and $A_{n+1}$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $B_nB_{n+1}$,
we have the recursive relations:
$$
b_n={a_n+a_{n+1}\over2\cos\theta},\quad
a_{n+1}={b_n+b_{n+1}\over2\cos\theta}.
$$
We can then eliminate $b_n$ to find the single recursion:
$$
a_{n+2}=2\cos2\theta\,a_{n+1}-a_n.
$$
[This can be solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) to yield (notice that I start with $n=0$):
$$
a_n=a_0\cos2n\theta+{a_1-a_0\cos2\theta\over\sin2\theta}\sin2n\theta.
$$

Finally, we can substitute $a_1$ in the above equation with its expression in terms of $a_0$ and $d$ (of course one needs $d\ge a_0\sin\theta$):
$$
a_1=a_0\cos2\theta\pm2\cos\theta\sqrt{d^2-a_0^2\sin^2\theta},
$$
obtaining:
$$
a_n=a_0\cos2n\theta\pm{\sqrt{d^2-a_0^2\sin^2\theta}\over\sin\theta}\sin2n\theta.
$$
The choice of the sign depends on the choice made at the first step, because given $A_0$ we have two possible choices for $B_0$. Notice that this formula also works for $\theta=\pi/2$, even if the original formula didn't.

It is then apparent that $\{a_n\}$ is finite if and only if $\theta=\pi/k$, with $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\ge2$.

[image]

Comment: hi I was revisiting this problem and may I ask how can I arrive at the recursive relationship? Thank you

Comment: You can infer it from the diagram: $b_n$ is the hypotenuse of a triangle with cathetus $(a_n+a_{n+1})/2$ and adjacent angle $\theta$, hence $(a_n+a_{n+1})/2=b_n\cos\theta$. The same for $a_{n+1}$ and $(b_n+b_{n+1})/2$.

Comment: oh thank you! Then is there a technique to solve the recurrence relationship?

Comment: Yes, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: Dear Aretino, I think there might be some mistake in your solution or in mine( I am not sure about that) Could you enter the chat room and maybe I would take a picture of how I am approaching it

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything Sorry for the delay, but I'm afraid we are on different time zones. Here's the chat room I created: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75199/discussion-between-aretino-and-guy-who-failed-everything

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything Anyway, I checked again my result with GeoGebra and it gives the correct points, so I presume it is correct.

Comment: Yes I am sorry; I combined the results of an and bn; it gave quite a different recurrence but I did manage to solve this. Thank you!